# how to convert an object to an array and pull data out of it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object, I'm trying to convert it to an array first and loop through the array and print it in the console but still, it does not destruct the array, it gives me an object.

````
const person = [

    {
        firstName : 'John',
        age : '24'
    }
];

const btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.innerText = 'Click';
document.body.appendChild(btn);

btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

    let newarray = Object.entries(person);

    newarray = person.map((get)=>{

        const {firstName, age} = get;
        return {firstName, age};
    });

    console.log(newarray);

});```
````

Comment: You are destructuring the object, but then you create a new object in your return statement

Comment: You said you have an Object that you want transform to Array, and then you start your example with an Array. Although an array is still of type object, but what you should tell us what your Input is, and how you would like your Output to look like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want nested array in your newArray then do the following:

```
newarray = person.map((get)=>{

        const {firstName, age} = get;
        return [firstName, age];
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by you are trying to convert it to an array? To get the key values you can use Object.keys or for values you can use Object.values.

Comment: Hi Santhini, Welcome to SO, Please try to avoid questions in your answers. Also it is always better to include `code snippets` in support of your Answer, TIP : well elaborated and explained answer with optional [source links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) always look beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Some points to clarify:

Variable `const person = [{}]` would be better named as `persons`, as an array of multiple persons, to avoid confusion to others. Also `get` variable in map would be better as `person` or `per` or `p`.

Immediate assignment without using the variable is useless:

```
let newarray = Object.entries(person); // useless assignment

newarray = person.map(...);
```

You need to clearly indicate what is your Input object, and how you expect your Output Array to be like.

I'm thinking that your input is Array of Object, and you want an Array of Array of Values in orders like:

```
// output
[ ['John', 24], ['Bob', 25], ['Carl', 23] ]
```

If it's the case, then you can use `Object.values` to convert object into Array of values:

```
const persons = [
    {
        firstName : 'John',
        age : 24
    }
];

const btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.innerText = 'Click';
document.body.appendChild(btn);

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {

    let newarray = persons.map((person) => {
        return Object.values(person);
    });

    console.log(newarray); // [ ['John', 24] ]
});
```